# Reduce white space in word cloud zingcharts?

Tags: d3.js, removing-whitespace, word-cloud, zingchart

I am trying to make word cloud using zingcharts. But I am not able to reduce white space between the words and make the word cloud more compact.

[Current Version of word cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1yA5.png)

I want something like this.

[Ideal wordcloud version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opbfS.jpg)

**Code for generating word cloud.**

```js
var myConfig = {
              type: 'wordcloud',
              options: {  
              words:arr,
              minLength: 4,
              colorType: 'palette',
              palette:['#99bbff','#80aaff','#6699ff','#4d88ff','#3377ff','#1a66ff','#0055ff','#004de6','#0044cc','#003cb3','#003399'].reverse()
            }
          };

    zingchart.render({
      id: 'myChart',
      data: myConfig,
      height: '500px',
      width: '65%'
    });
```

Is there any way to do this ? I was not able to find any such property in zingcharts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the spacing between words by setting the padding in the style object like so:

style: {
      padding: '-1px'
      }

Here is an example of modified spacing on a wordchart: https://demos.zingchart.com/view/BHHBSRA8

Comment: Thank you so much. But reducing the padding makes the words collide. I mean there is still white space between 'United states' .